# Why is positional encoding preferable over adding additional features for transformer models?

Tags: transformer, encoding

Why is information about the position not added as an additional feature? I read in forums that the only reason would be length-based overfitting, but I couldn't find a reliable source for that. What if the transformer is used for applications where length-based overfitting is not an issue due to consistent sequence length?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Positional encoding is an additional feature. I'm not sure what difference you are thinking of.